# PHPUnit Folder Execution with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I have the following route on my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    echo getcwd();
    var_dump(scandir('data'));
});
```

The folder is on `public/data` and when I access on the browser `localhost/` it works.
But when I run the following test

```
public function testOnline()
{
    $response = $this->get('/');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

It throws error 500 because it is executing on the project folder instead of the public folder.
I don't understand if this is proper behavior, and didn't find any answer on my searches.
But it just feels wrong to have to use absolute path everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Laravel so you should use [Laravel's helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#available-methods) to find the directories you need:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    var_dump(scandir(public_path('data')));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I just want to understand why the root path for phpunit and browser execution are different..

Comment: Because you run PHPUnit from the commandline and so `getcwd` is based on where you ran it from. When you run it from the browser then the webserver usually switches the working directory to the webpage entry point path.